# $L^2$-norm of double integral finite?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Let $T>0$ and set
$$
f_T(x,y)= e^{-(T-\min(x, y))}\Big(1-e^{-(T-\max(x,y))}\Big)1_{[0,T]^2}(x,y),
$$
where $1_A$ is the indicator function of a set $A$. For $s,t\in[0,T]$ and $\alpha\in(1,\frac32)$ set
$$
F_{\alpha,T}(s,t)=\int_s^\infty\int_t^\infty\frac{f_T(v,u)-f_T(v,t)-f_T(s,u)+f_T(s,t)}{(u-t)^\alpha(v-s)^\alpha}\,du\,dv.
$$
For which $\alpha\in(1,\frac32)$ is
$$
\limsup_{T\to\infty}\int_0^T\int_0^T\big|F_{\alpha,T}(s,t)\big|^2\,ds\,dt<\infty?
$$
By symmetry, it's actually to estimate $F_{\alpha,T}(s,t)$ for $s\leq t$ (or $s\geq t$). I tried to do a brute force computation but this leads to quite a number of case distinctions...

Comment: What's the context of such a complicated integrand? It seems like something related to renewal theory. Anyway, please see [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508).